# HangupAction asterisk java

Tags: java, spring, asterisk

I am trying to perform calls using asterisk pbx from front end application.
My backend side is written in java and I am using Spring framework.
For now I am able to initiate call using the following service:

```
@Service("callHandlingService")
public class AsteriskCallHandlingServiceImpl implements AsteriskCallHandlingService {

private ManagerConnection managerConnection;

public void initiateCall(String caller, String callee) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, AuthenticationFailedException, TimeoutException {
    ManagerConnectionFactory factory = new ManagerConnectionFactory(
            "0.0.0.0", 5038, "test", "test");
    this.managerConnection = factory.createManagerConnection();
    OriginateAction originateAction;
    ManagerResponse originateResponse;

    originateAction = new OriginateAction();
    originateAction.setChannel("SIP/" +caller);
    originateAction.setContext("default");
    originateAction.setExten(callee);
    originateAction.setPriority(new Integer(1));
    originateAction.setTimeout(new Integer(30000));

    managerConnection.login();
    originateResponse = managerConnection
            .sendAction(originateAction, 30000);
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
@Controller
public class CallController {
@Autowired
private AsteriskCallHandlingService callHandlingService;

@Autowired
private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/originateCall/{caller}/{callee}")
public void callNumber(@DestinationVariable String caller, @DestinationVariable String callee) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, AuthenticationFailedException, TimeoutException {
    callHandlingService.initiateCall(caller, callee);
}
```

My question is how to terminate the connection between the caller and callee?
I have an idea to add one more method in the service `hangup(String callee)` 
I could not find any example and I hope somebody can give me a hint about it.
Thank you very much!
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need listen events, that way you can determine which channel name assigned for you need channel.

After that you can do "core soft hangup channel XXXX" action via AMI.

There are no easy way do that without dialplan support. But you can organize dialplan so it record for you channel name before call out.

In general it is very bad idea write dialler-like code without fully understanding how asterisk work. If you can't spend time for learing use vicidial.org or other opensource dialling core.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have class that listens for all of the events in my asterisk and maybe I should try to use it instead of writing my own methods for hanging up.